# point an A record of Domain to another server and redirect any http to https for that subdomain.

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, cname

I have created an A record on my main domain that points to another IP address for a web application. 
Ex: account.mydomain.com has an A record that points to a third party server ex: 255.255.255.xxx

My issue is:
if someone goes to: http://account.mydomain.com they receive an error.
if they go to:      https://account.mydomain.com then it works.

I cant use a redirect because that subdomain is simply an A record. How can I fix this so http redirects to https only for that A record "account.mydomain.com"?

Thanks ahead of time for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^account\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Try to provide all the details just `I couldn't make that work` won't help you. What URL did you try and what error you got?

Comment: I added that to my .htaccess file, but it did not reroute to the https.

Comment: I changed the `^account\.mydomain\.com$` to my actual A Record and Domain name.

Comment: Did you place above rule in DOCUMENT_ROOT of `account.mydomain.com`? Do you have .htaccess and mod_rewrite enabled?